# Modular form on $\Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, modular-forms

I recently asked this [question on Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684079/modular-form-on-gamma-0n) with no answer so far. So I thought maybe I can find an answer here.

Let $M(k,\Gamma_0(N))$ be a space of modular forms of weight $k$ on $\Gamma_0(N)$.
Each $f \in M(k,\Gamma_0(N))$ has a Fourier expansion of the form
$$ f(\tau)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a(n)\,q^n \quad \text{where}\quad q=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}\tau} . $$

Now, let $g(\tau)$ be a function obtained from $f(\tau)$ by omitting all $a(n)$ such that $\gcd(n,N)\neq 1$, i.e.
$$ g(\tau)=\sum_{\substack{n\in \mathbb{N}\\(n,N)=1}}a(n)\,q^n . $$

**Question:** Is $g(\tau)$ a modular form? What is its level?

Many thanks.

Comment: Dear @user31009, perhaps you should wait at least a few days (instead of 20 hours) before reposting your Math.StackExchange question on MathOverflow. Quick reposting leads to duplication of effort, and is frowned upon by both communities.

Comment: Not to mention that questions can be migrated.  You can flag a question for migration by a moderator, in which case people can follow the link to the other site, and there won't be duplication.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good question and should not be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ g(\tau)=f(\tau)\otimes \left(\tfrac{N^2}{\cdot}\right)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(\tfrac{N^2}{n}\right)a(n)\,q^n \quad \text{where}\left(\tfrac{N^2}{\cdot}\right) \text{ is the Kronecker symbol}.$$
This means that $g(\tau)$ is just the twist of $f(\tau)$ by a principle character. Indeed we have $$g(\tau)\in M(k,\Gamma_0(N^3)).$$

Comment: In fact a stronger conclusion can be drawn, see my response.

Answer (score 11):

We can express the form $g(\tau)$ as
$$ g(\tau)=\sum_{d\mid N}\mu(d)\sum_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\d\mid n}} a(n)\,q^n.$$
In the notation of Atkin-Lehner (Hecke operators on $\Gamma_0(m)$, Math. Ann. 185 (1970), 134-160), the inner sum is $(f\mid U_d)\mid B_d$, which lies in $M(k,\Gamma_0(dN))$ by Lemmata 2, 6, 14 in the paper. This implies that 
$$ g\in M(k,\Gamma_0(N^2)). $$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes it is a modular form. For this (and the level) see Section 3.8 of Soma Purkait's [thesis](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maslau/thesis.pdf).

Comment: This seems like a bit more generality than necessary - doesn't the modularity follow straightforwardly from properties of $U_p$ and $V_p$?

Comment: @Carnahan: You are right, see my response.